# Horizontal navigation with vertical scrollbar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I want the Page to scroll horizontally but using the vertical scrollbar.
I've made a div with id lay of width 7000px. I'm rotating this div to -90deg and so that on vertical scrolling it moves horizontally

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#lay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7000px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateX();
}
```

```html
<div id="lay"></div>
```

Comment: Why would you do that? There are usability rules that you should follow to give your user a nice experience.

Comment: I want to try it out. Sorry for the messy code btw, I'm just starting out

Comment: There is no question actually. So what help do you need?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/  .Here's a link to what i want to do, but as you can see demo is not working properly.When the user scrolls using a vertical scroll bar,the page navigates vertically